# passing string of arguments in a url string

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp-classic

My variables:

```
var strArgsString = "?Category=Customer&Year=2014";
var intModuleNo = "2";
var strOrigDashName = "Invoices"
```

My AJAX Post:

```
    var jqxhr = $.post("includes/saveParameters.asp?dname="+strOrigDashName+"&mod="+intModuleNo+"&args='"+strArgsString+"'", function() {
    alert("success");
})
.fail(function() {
    alert("error");
});
```

It returns a fail because the "args" value is treated as a continuation of the full query string. 
Im sure there will be many ways to do this but how can i get "?Category=Customer&Year=2014" treated as a string on my .asp file?

At the moment I have these

```
strDashboardName = Request.QueryString("dname")
intModuleNumber = Request.QueryString("mod")
strParamsArgString = Request.QueryString("args")
```

Any solution appreciated, but preferance given to the most efficient, thanks.

Comment: Yes, use `encodeURIComponent();` and then `QueryString` will automatically decode it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to encode the args string so it can be represented as data, and not a literal continuation of the querystring.

```
var strArgsString = encodeURIComponent("?Category=Customer&Year=2014");
var intModuleNo = "2";
var strOrigDashName = "Invoices"
```

There are two additional options for encoding.  encodeURI and escape.  Please see [Best practice: escape, or encodeURI / encodeURIComponent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent) for further information.

Comment: encodeURIComponent got the desired result thanks. Sometimes you cant search for something when you dont know the solution.

Comment: I'm sorry if I sounded like I meant you should have found the best practice prior to asking.  That is NOT what I meant.  I meant if you were curious about the differences that you could find the information there.  I'm very familiar with the problem of search terms. =)